# ¿Existen rutas relativas para conectar la base de datos a un reporte Crystal?

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports, report, oledb

Buen día, tengo un proyecto de C# en el cual utilizo una base de datos Access. La base de datos esta ubicada en la ruta: `ProyectoSolucion\proyecto\bin\Debug\base.accdb.` para trabajar en el sistema

Tengo un reporte de Crystal con el cual quiero conectar la base de datos, el problema es que la ruta que ingreso par hacer la conexión es algo como `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\ProyectoSolucion2\proyecto\bin\Debug`. Entonces obviamente al usar el proyecto en otro equipo o moverlo a otro lugar, la conexión se vería afectada.

Mi pregunta es si existe la manera de ingresar una ruta relativa, para evitar que se pierda la conexión.

La manera en que lo intento hacer es usando **el asistente de bases de datos**
, seleccionando una nueva conexión OLEDB.

[image: Asistente de bases de datos]

selecciono el **`Microsoft Office 12.0 Database Engine OLE DB Provider`**, y en la siguiente ventana es donde agrego la ruta.

[image: Ruta de la BD]

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que averiguar el nombre del origen de datos y cambiarle la conexión.

Que la base de datos esté en `ProyectoSolucion\proyecto\bin\Debug\base.accdb` significa que está en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable, por lo que le debes asignar la misma ruta que la encontrarás en `Application.StartupPath`.

Por ejemplo, si tu conexión se llama **conn** le asignarás una nueva cadena de conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath;
```

Comment: De esta manera tendría que hacer la conexión mediante el código donde mando a llamar al reporte y no desde el diseño del reporte?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es hacerlo en el código, pero puedes reutilizar el que realizas en el diseño y reescribir la cadena de conexión.

Comment: No utilizo ningún código en el diseño. El unico codigo que uso es para asignarle al viewer como `DataSource` el reporte. Y para mostrar el ReportViewer en otro formulario.